# Suppose A is a set of premises of an argument and B the conclusion of that argument. Prove that if A U {¬B} ⊢ ⊥, then A ⊢ B

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, fitch

Suppose A is a set of premises of an argument and B the conclusion of that argument. Prove that if A U {¬B} ⊢ ⊥, then A ⊢ B. (Use Fitch)

I have no idea where to start, can someone help?

Comment: The operator symbol you use for A (op) B does not render on my Android cellphone.   Can you rewrite?  Second, $\cup$ is not a logical symbol.  Do you mean $A\land\not B$?

Comment: @mobileink - **A** is a *set* of premises (but to use a different type of symbols - like **Γ** - would be better...); thus **Γ U {¬B}** is correct: it means the "enlarged" set of premises "made of" all the formulae in **Γ** plus **¬B**.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: understood, my nitpicky point is that FOL is not set theory.  $ \Gamma, A\vdash B $ is not necessarily synonymous with $\Gamma\cup A\vdash B$.  (Sorry I can't get Latex markup to work.)

Comment: It is written that way in many textbooks... See e.g. [van Dalen](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA35), **Lemma 2.4.3** (g), page 35.

Comment: OP: is your question about how Fitch style proofs work?

Answer (score 1):

Assume A U {¬B} ⊢ ⊥

Now we need to show that A ⊢ B:

Assume ¬B, get a contradiction from premise A and from A U {¬B} ⊢ ⊥, and then conclude B. (You should fill here the natural deduction steps.) That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Eliran H's answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/33894/29944).

Here are specific steps using a Fitch-style proof checker without assuming "¬B".

The proof uses disjunction introduction (∨I), conditional elimination (→E), explosion (X) and conditional introduction (→I). Further information on these rules may be found in *forall x: Calgary Remix*.

[image]

---

References

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/